# Java bat doesn`t work

Tags: java, batch-file

When starting bat in this way:

```
path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin
cd C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Lab1\src\main
javac Main.java
cd C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Lab1\src\
java main.Main asd ads fgh
pause
```

I have an error “Cannot find symbol: class Reader”.

Comment: Two options: Post your code, remove images. OR wait for a mind reader.

Comment: It doesn't help that you're creating a class called `Reader` when there's already `java.io.Reader`. That's a recipe for confusion.

Comment: This has nothing to do with batch files, by the way - you'd get exactly the same issue if you just ran the same commands one at a time from the command line.

Comment: Third option: wait for Jon Skeet.

Comment: If i use SymbolReader insted of Reader i have same result. Promblem isn`t in the class name.

Comment: Either, compile all `.java` files at once or use the `-sourcepath` option to tell `javac` where to search for the other `.java` source files. The specified directory must be the *base* directory if you are using packages, i.e. if you declare your classes within `package main`, you must specify the *parent* of the `main` directory.

Answer (score 1):

The big problem with

```
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin
```

is that after it is run from the cmd prompt, subsequent commands from the cmd prompt will not work.  Also

```
set classpath=%CLASSPATH%;C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Lab2\src\
```

will keep on growing classpath everytime the script is executed.  You can get round this problem by using setlocal and endlocal.

```
setlocal
set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin
set classpath=%CLASSPATH%;C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Lab2\src\
....
endlocal
```

That way, when it is executed multiple times from a cmd prompt, the path will not change and the classpath will not keep on growing.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to recreate this issue using bat file.

pls update setclasspath in your bat file to include the following path

set classpath=%CLASSPATH%;C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Lab2\src\

Once classpath is update, u can compile all java files individually

Comment: Thx, i foun another option to solve problem, but your comment is really helpfull.